# Why Does String Interpolation Only Work In Double Quotes PHP

Tags: php, string, string-interpolation

I've noticed through programming in PHP that string interpolation (`"blah blah ${foo}"`) only works in double-quoted strings (`"..."`).

For instance, this line will work:

```
$bar = "foo";
echo "I like ${bar}";

>> I like foo
```

But this one won't:

```
$bar = "foo";
echo 'I like ${bar}';

>> I like ${bar}
```

I understand that the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) talks about the fact that interpolation is only acted upon in such strings, but it doesn't explain why it was chosen to work in this way.

So that's my question --- *why* is it that string interpolation only works in double-quoted strings in PHP?

Comment: In PHP, whatever is inside the double quotes gets parsed before outputing, anything inside a single quote gets treated as a string.

Comment: Better question might be who thought backtick ([execution](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)) operators were a good idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious answer is that there are times when you might not want variables to be interpreted in your strings.

Take, for example, the following line of code:

```
$currency = "$USD";
```

This produces an "undefined variable" notice and `$currency` is an empty string. Definitely not what you want.

You *could* escape it (`"\$USD"`), but hey, that's a faff.

So PHP, as a design decision, chose to have double-quoted strings interpolated and single-quoted strings not.

Comment: Added benefit of not needing to parse 'single quote strings'. Which is a good reason to default to them. Performance.

Comment: @ficuscr [Not really...](http://nikic.github.io/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html)

Comment: As in not a good default or performance is really moot? ahh, a link to read.

Comment: @ficuscr As in the performance difference is at most negligible, when it exists at all.

Comment: Good read. Thanks for sharing. While I agree, it still comes down to right tool for the right job in my mind. Don't use preg when a string function will do (OK not a good comparison). Maybe crux for me is code readability. Same reason I prefer "Hello {$world}".

Comment: @ficuscr Yeah, "use the right tool for the job" is a pretty sensible principle in general!

Answer (score -3):

It works that way by definition. That's the way it was made to work. There is no 'why' other than that's the way the developers of PHP chose to implement the feature.

Comment: Why waste your time or anyone else's with a non-answer?

Comment: @NateVaughan let's be more kind and provide other point of views - if there are 2 ways to do something and each works a bit differently - in 95% cases there **is** a reason why it was done in that way. This is 99% true especially for string outputting constructs :-) If you would be absolutely sure there was no apparent reason - please provide a link/reference proving that.